# Fullcalendar : Duplicates on agendaWeek view

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to use FullCalendar v2.4.0 (with jQuery 1.10.2 and moment.js 2.1) in order to display events that are stored in a database.
I'm using json to send events to FullCalendar.

I have some problems of duplicated events in the 'agendaWeek' view.
Everything is working properly for the other views ('month', 'basicWeek', 'basicDay', 'agendaDay').

As i read on stackoverflow, I tried to remove the event source, to remove events,... but i'm still facing the problem.

Here's how the code looks like :

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next,today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultDate: '<?=date("Y-m-d")?>',
    defaultView: 'agendaDay',
    timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
    displayEventEnd: true,
    events: {
        url: '/events_getlist_json.php',
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        error: function() {
            alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $(data).each(function(index) {
                console.log( index + ": " + data[index].start );
            })
        }
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');
    }, 100);
});
```

The console log returns 2 events : "0: 2015-08-24T11:00:00" and "1: 2015-08-26T12:30:00" but i can see 4 of them on the calendar.

If you have any idea why duplicates happen in 'agendaWeek' view only, and how to remove them, it would be really nice to help.
Thank you in advance.

**edit :** added version of the 3 scripts

Comment: What happens if you get rid of the `setTimeout`? It's the only thing I see that looks like a possible source of problems.

Comment: if i get rid of it, the calendar doesn't render : i'll just have the  'prev', 'next', 'today', 'month', 'week', and 'day' buttons displaying. And i'll get no console log at all.

Comment: hmm. Stick the whole fullcalendar init code into that `setTimeout` box, then. See if the problem still exists.

Comment: by doing so, the calendar renders, but the duplication on the 'agendaWeek' view still exists.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: sorry for forgetting about it : FullCalendar v2.4.0

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue on my end, so let's take a look at the events when they come in. Add an [`eventDataTransform`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/eventDataTransform/) callback and log the events that come through (then return the event object).

Comment: `eventDataTransform :function(data) {
console.log(data);
return {
id: data.id,
title: data.title,
start: data.start,
end: data.end,
url: data.url,
allDay: data.allDay
};
}`

The console log is like this : Object {id: "2", title: "Event title", url: "", start: "2015-08-24T11:00:00", end: "2015-08-24T12:00:00", allDay: false}
Object {id: "1", title: "Other event title", url: "", start: "2015-08-26T12:30:00", end: "2015-08-26T16:45:00", allDay: false}

Comment: if you hardcode in the events, does it still happen? Try with this code: http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/fgnf16fj/

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. I tried to hardcode the events, with all the JS of my project removed (keeping jquery 1.10.2, bootstrap 3.1.1, and fullcalendar 2.4.0). Even like this, duplicates still happen (on the agendaWeek view only).

Comment: Alright, cut the JS down to this: http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/fgnf16fj/1/

Comment: It's crazy to say it still happens. Events are still duplicated in the column of the previous day.

Comment: Unmodified FC? Newest moment.js? Try on more than one browser. And try this fiddle and post the console results: http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/fgnf16fj/2/

Comment: Yeah, unmodified latest FC. Regarding moment.js, it was 2.1, **I updated moment.js to 2.10.6 and now it's working as it should**. Thanks a lot for your time and your help @slicedtoad. I spent more than 20 hours trying to fix this, you're my savior !

Comment: Awesome. I was starting to shoot in the dark there for a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This was worked out in the comment between the OP and I.*

**Fullcalendar 2.4.0 conflicts with momentjs 2.1** causing duplicate events to appear in the agendaWeek view. Upgrade to the latest [momentsjs](http://momentjs.com/) to fix the issue.